# How to summarize view-components/widgets-information in a JAR-File?

Tags: ajax, frameworks, jar, toolkit

I would like to use an ajax toolkit/framework like ZK (www.zkoss.org) or GWT. But I don't know whether it's possible to bundle resources in a JAR? Do you know which one support such resource loading?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your goal is, but if its to bundle a web application into one file, then you can do that with a WAR file - assuming your deploying onto a java webcontainer like tomcat or jboss.

Answer (score 0):

My goal is to summarize the Java-classes and also their Templates-files for the view of various application modules, each in one Java-Jar-File. These modules I use in another application, which of course I summarize in a WAR-File for Deployment. I would like to know which ajax-Framework/Toolkit does support this.

Comment: Just a point of order: you should add this clarification by editing the question, not by adding an answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.ztemplates.org which is simple and easy to learn. This one allows you to put all related templates, javascript and css into one jar and use it transparently. Means you even have not to care about declaring the needed javascript in your page when using a provided component, as the framework does it for you.